# Annoying blank console at the back of my GUI form

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, console, g++

I compile this small program using GCC (g++) compiler. The result executable is fine but when I run it, it comes up with an annoying blank console window! :(

```
 #include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static char gszClassName[]  = "darkblue";
static HINSTANCE ghInstance = NULL;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
        WNDCLASSEX WndClass;
        HWND hwnd;
        MSG Msg;

        ghInstance = hInstance;

        WndClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        WndClass.style         = NULL;
        WndClass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
        WndClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        WndClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        WndClass.hInstance     = ghInstance;
        WndClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        WndClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        WndClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        WndClass.lpszClassName = gszClassName;
        WndClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

        if(!RegisterClassEx(&WndClass)) {
                MessageBox(0, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
                return 0;
        }

        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                WS_EX_STATICEDGE,
                gszClassName,
                "darkblue owNz!",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                320, 240,
                NULL, NULL,
                ghInstance,
                NULL);

        if(hwnd == NULL) {
                MessageBox(0, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
                return 0;
        }

        ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);

        while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
                TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        return Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        switch(Message) {
                case WM_CLOSE:
                        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                        break;
                case WM_DESTROY:
                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                        break;
                default:
                        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post screen shot window ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're compiling your code to target the `CONSOLE` subsystem, which is why the black console window is appearing upon execution of your application.

This is the default option in GCC, probably because it's easy to get going: all you need are a few `cout` lines and you can get text on the screen immediately. With the console window, you don't have to go through all of the trouble of creating a window etc., as you've done here.

In this case, you actually want to link to the `WINDOWS` subsystem. That's how you create a typical GUI application. There are two ways of doing that:

1. You can specify the `-mwindows` linker option on the command line.
2. You can add the following line to the linker flags in your makefile:

   ```
   -Wl,-subsystem,windows
   ```